# SPL token metadata

Tags: token, metadata, spl

Tell me please. I have created a SPL token, how do I add the website and social networks to the metadata now? Previously, this could be done with the help of PR on github.

Answer (score 1):

This was changed due to the PR method not scaling.

Now tokens support metadata and you can easily create one via:

https://app.strataprotocol.com/launchpad

Comment: Yes, but I can’t add a website and social networks to metodata. Else when creating a token on https://app.strataprotocol.com/launchpad in explorer, it says a warning that the token is not unique